# Is there a way to view the 2 connected DAGs in one graph view?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I have 2 `DAGS`:

1. `example_call_other_dag` which looks:

[image]

The second task (`TriggerDagRunOperator`) call the second `DAG`:

2. `example_xcom` which looks:

[image]

Is there a way to view the 2 connected `DAG`s in one `graph view` ?

I wan't see something like:

[image]

Is it possible ? How can I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Airflow has Dag Dependencies view
[image]

You can access it via Browse -> Dag Dependencies:

[image]

The view exist for Airflow>=2.1.0

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I expected, I updated the question with a suitable image

Comment: No such view exist